# Difficulty understanding Jquery code

Tags: jquery

I have included an accordion within a site im working on, one content area includes a youtube video which I have successfully managed to stop when another accordion header is selected thanks to Stack overflow, however I am having trouble in understanding how it actually functions. I am pretty new to Jquery and would like to understand how this works in order to implement future scripts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, the Jquery is shown below.

Thanks,

Melissa

```
$(".accordion h3").eq(40).addClass("active");
$(".accordion div").eq(40).show();
$(".accordion h3").click(function(){
    var video = $(".accordion h3.active").next().children();
    var src = video.attr("src");
    video.attr("src","");
    video.attr("src",src);

    $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow")
    .siblings("div").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Every selector and method mentioned above is covered [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). [There are tutorials](http://learn.jquery.com/) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some explanatory comments here, and hopefully that'll help.

```
$(".accordion h3").eq(40).addClass("active");
$(".accordion div").eq(40).show();
$(".accordion h3").click(function(){
    var video = $(".accordion h3.active").next().children(); // Find the div containing the video

    // The following three lines are a hack to stop the video.
    var src = video.attr("src"); // Get the source of the video
    video.attr("src","");  // Set the source to ""
    video.attr("src",src); // Set the source back to the original source.

    // Find the next div and toggle its state (sliding animation) while sliding up other divs (animated)
    $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow")
    .siblings("div").slideUp("slow");

    // and toggle this one's active state
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    // while making the others inactive
    $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Christian, now that I see these, it makes much more sense! Thanks again!